# how to search for a specific file in blob storage

Tags: c#, blob, blobstore, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am kind of new to Blob storage and i need to access a specific file from blob storage.
i.e when i type in a specific folder it should list out all the blobs underneath it.

Can anyone help me with that

here's the code which i am trying to do.

```
if (AccountFileTransfer != null)
{
    BlobClientFileTransfer = AccountFileTransfer.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    ContainerFileTransfer = BlobClientFileTransfer.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);


    CloudBlob blob = ContainerFileTransfer.GetBlobReference(txtFileSearch.Text);
    if (blob.Uri == null)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Not a Valid blob search");
    }
    else
    {
        lvFileTransfer.Items.Add(blob.Uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Azure Search` to index and search for files in Blob storage

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (AccountFileTransfer != null) 
{

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = 
    new CloudBlobClient(blobEndpoint, 
                        new StorageCredentialsAccountAndKey(accountName, accountKey));


    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);


    foreach (var blobItem in container .ListBlobs())
    {
        lvFileTransfer.Items.Add(blobItem .Uri);  
    }

}
```

Comment: this code i have already tried and it will list only the root structure it is not going in depth or underneath the folders

Answer (score 0):

Try this and If the blob in a Directory in container, in that case following format
            container.GetBlobReference("Images/" + fileName);

```
    public static bool BlobExists(CloudBlobContainer container, string fileName)
    {
        var blob = container.GetBlobReference(fileName);

        try
        {
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            return true;
        }
        catch (StorageException e)
        {
            if (e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```